# In what cases can a DNS master file contain a CRLF?

Tags: dns, rfc, rfc1035

While reading [RFC 1035 Section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5.1) in order to write a master file parser, I stumbled across the following statement:

> #### 5.1. Format
>
> The format of these files is a sequence of entries.  Entries are
> predominantly line-oriented, though parentheses can be used to continue
> a list of items across a line boundary, and **text literals can contain
> CRLF within the text**.  Any combination of tabs and spaces act as a
> delimiter between the separate items that make up an entry.  The end of
> any line in the master file can end with a comment.  The comment starts
> with a ";" (semicolon).

What do the authors mean by *"text literals can contain CRLF within the text"*? I am aware that the beneath entry is valid as outlined in [Section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5.3) but I fail to find either an example of the statement or a proper definition of *"text literal"*. I have furthermore searched the companion [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) without success for any mention of the above statement.

```
@   IN  SOA     VENERA      Action\.domains (
                                 20     ; SERIAL
                                 7200   ; REFRESH
                                 600    ; RETRY
                                 3600000; EXPIRE
                                 60)    ; MINIMUM
```

I would assume a text literal could be delimited by parentheses. Would any of the following comments be valid per RFC 1035 and in what different ways would a CRLF be valid in the file?

```
@   IN  SOA     VENERA      Action\.domains (
                                 20     ;  Some example of a multi-line comment 
                                           inside parentheses
                                 7200
                                 600
                                 3600000
                                 60)    ;  (Some example of parentheses
                                           inside a multi-line comment)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that this is supposed to be valid:

```
example.com. IN TXT "hello,
world"
```

The RFC authors probably expect it to be equivalent to:

```
example.com. IN TXT "hello,\013\010world"
```

Due to the ambiguity of line ending encodings in this situations (if the platform uses LF as the line terminator, do you still get CRLF in the TXT record?), I doubt this is widely implemented.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out! How about a CRLF in a comment `[...] ; " [...] \r\n [...]"` ?